# Stack Navigation with tab and drawer navigation

Tags: react-native

Scenario:

After selecting the "Go To Detail" button, I would like to navigate to a new page without the bottom tab navigator.

Problem:

However, the bottom tab navigator is still there.

[image: Problem]

Possible solution:

Push the "DetailView" via the root view instead of "HomeView" stack. But how to do it?

[Expo project link](https://snack.expo.io/@torresho/t_navigation)

***Updated***

Changed the Drawer Navigator to include DetailNavigator, however the transition is rather abrupt and it's added to drawer which is unwanted behavior:

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: BottomTabNavigator,
    Settings: SettingsNavigator,
    Detail: DetailNavigator
});

export const DetailNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Detail: { screen: DetailScreen }
});

After changing (DetailView appear abruptly):

[image: After]

Before changing (DetailView appear smoothly with animation):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably want to hide tab bar on specific screens without changing your navigators structure, take a look here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html#a-tab-navigator-contains-a-stack-and-you-want-to-hide-the-tab-bar-on-specific-screens

Comment: Thanks Max for pointing me to this wonderful link... Managed to solve it by adding another stack navigator as a parent of the tab navigator, and put the details screen there. And hide the header.